# What populates this array list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My array list somehow becomes populated.

Look at this code:

```
final ListView list = getListView();
boolean threadNeeded = true;
//settings
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
allFriends = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("shibby.whisper.allFriends");
selectedFriends = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("shibby.whisper.selectedFriends");
System.out.println("JUST ENTERED ACTIVITY : "+selectedFriends.getPositions());

if(extras !=null) {
    maxPlayers = extras.getInt("max_players");
}

if(allFriends != null){
    if(!allFriends.getIds().isEmpty()){
        threadNeeded = false;
    }
}

if(selectedFriends == null){
    System.out.println("selectedFriends is null before callback from ListActivity");
    selectedFriends = new PlayerList();
}

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FacebookFriendsAdapter a = (FacebookFriendsAdapter) list.getAdapter();
        //select item
        boolean isSelected = a.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));

        //if reached maximum players and have selected a new user
        if(((maxPlayers+1 == a.getMaxPlayersCounter() && maxPlayers != 0) && isSelected)
            || (maxPlayers == 0 && a.getMaxPlayersCounter() == maxAvailablePlayers+1)){
            Log.e("addfriends","Max Players Reached");
            a.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));        
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(FacebookFriendsListActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme );
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maxplayers);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            Button dialogButton = (Button)       dialog.findViewById(R.id.max_players_dismiss_btn);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
});

m_friends = new ArrayList<Player>();
this.m_adapter = new FacebookFriendsAdapter(this, R.layout.facebbok_friends_item, m_friends);

//set the selected friends on the adapter to remember earlier picks
if(selectedFriends != null){
    oldPositions = selectedFriends.getPositions();
    m_adapter.setSelectedIds(selectedFriends.getPositions());
    m_adapter.setMaxPlayersCounter(selectedFriends.getIds().size());
    System.out.println("Max player selected Is : "+maxPlayers+" And Selected Players Counter Is :" +m_adapter.getMaxPlayersCounter());
}
```

When the activity starts, the `selectedFriends.getPosition()` returns empty.

When I click a button I do this action:

```
if(oldPositions != null){
    System.out.println("This is old positions : " + oldPositions);
}
```

Which is populated (by the new position), but I don't see why. Am I referencing something I shouldn't? Do I override the data in memory?

**EDIT :** This happens after I select some friends from the ListView. `toggleSelected()` adds or removes item from an inner ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is assuming that this line makes a copy of whatever `getPositions` return:

```
oldPositions = selectedFriends.getPositions();
```

Actually it only makes a copy of the reference - it doesn't make a shallow copy of the entire list.

You probably want something like this (I'm just guessing the type):

```
oldPositions = new ArrayList<Position>(selectedFriends.getPositions());
```

Comment: Yes i am aware of that, but the thing is that it's not suppoused to be filled with anything, as i mentioned in the begining of the activity it is empty.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: When you print it, you are showing the *current* contents of the list, not the contents it had at the beginning of the activity.

Comment: Holy potato! doing that solved the problem! but i don't understand how could it have been populated? i understand what you're saying but i'm not changing it at all, in the end of the code i populate that array with the releavent data

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Because someone (probably *you*) put things into the list after you copied the reference. You assumed that `a=b;` means "Please make a copy of this list for me, and make sure my copy  doesn't change even if the original changes." But that's not what `=` does. All it does is copy the reference (a reference is similar to a pointer). Both references still refer to the same list.

Comment: That's the thing <i>i</i> didn't put things in it. If you look the adapter is seperate from the class. I'm not setting anything to it at all at that point of the code. Unless i am missing that too :o

Comment: @eric.itzhak: It's hard to give a more complete answer unless you show the code to the rest of your program.